Short story about a mean man invaded by an extraterrestrial being who later became calm and kind and his wife denying alien presence to the police
A man (apparently called Lester) was very mean to his wife, constantly yelled at her and disliked their nephew. One day he gets sent to a (geological?) expedition to a planet far in the space and gets invaded by an invisible and bodyless extraterrestrial being, who basically replaces his personality. After coming back to Earth, he behaves like a very kind, calm, intelligent person, admiring his wife and super glad to see his nephew. Earthlings know about the… particularity of that planet and suspect that the man is not himself anymore. But the last word before the police applies their weapon against the alien is given to his wife who, guessing what happened, publicly denies any change in her husband. The story ends with a dialog between the wife and the person that is now her husband.
I saw this story in several collections.

This is Human Is by Philip K. Dick.

The plot centers on the crisis facing a woman whose cold and
emotionally abusive husband returns from a survey mission to the dying
planet Rexor IV, changed for the better—his psyche was replaced by a
Rexorian, glad to have escaped the confines of its dying planet.

You can read the full story here

Yes yes yes! Thank you so much, I'd been searching it for months now!

@AndréPolykanine - You're very welcome
